# Laravel on Google AppEngine: Any way to NOT write services.json?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel, laravel-4

Google AppEngine is my server platform of choice for all new apps. There is one caveat about GAE though: The disk is read-only. Writing to disk is simply not possible.

Is there a way to make Laravel NOT write `services.json` to the disk, other than mangling the framework itself to return true in `FileSystem->put()`?

Comment: There's a laravel tutorial for app engine here -> https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/ it might answer your question.